# Permalinks and custom PHP application

Tags: php, permalinks

I have Wordpress installed in the root directory and configured properly using permalinks.

Alongside the Wordpress blog, I have a full-fledged custom developed php application with several pages. I want to not show the .php extension for any of the custom pages, but I'm now getting 404 errors for all the custom php pages.

http://url/blog-title-here (word press page  - works)

http://url/register (custom php page - results in 404)

Here's what my .htaccess looks like:

```
# BEGIN WordPress 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L] 
</IfModule>
```

And here's what I have in httpd.conf

```
<Directory />
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]
</Directory>
```

Comment: It's a question about Apache, not WordPress.

Comment: this is a bad idea which will have surprising results when your authors create new page. keep the .php suffix or move your app to a subdirectory so at least there will be only one "illegal" slug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(EDIT) Take the custom rules outside the # Begin Wordpress (credit to Tim Malone)*

You can check if the file exists in the root and load it before the Wordpress rules kick in:

```
# check for a file, i.e register.php
# load it if found and stop processing the rest of the rules with the [L] flag
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$1.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)  /$1.php [L]
</IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L] 
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

http://url/register will then open the register.php file in the root.

If the file is not found, the Wordpress rules are processed.

Comment: Actually register.php is in the root directory, alongside .htaccess, and all the other wordpress files.

Comment: I'd probably put the custom rules outside of `#BEGIN WordPress`, not 100% sure but WordPress might override them if the rewrite rules are hard flushed (as they are when clicking Save on Settings -> Permalinks).

Comment: Tim is probably right, edited the answer!